# Can I stop an If statement from running if another's statement's requirements are met in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
# ask for user input
num1 = int(input('Input the first number to compare: '))
num2 = int(input('Input the second number to compare: '))
num3 = int(input('Input the third number to compare: '))

# identify which numbers are largest, second smallest and smallest
if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
    largest = num1
elif (num2 >= num1) and (not num3 >= num2):
    largest = num2
else:
    largest = num3

if (num1 <= num2) and (num1 <= num3):
    smallest = num1
elif (num2 <= num1) and (num2 <= num3):
    smallest = num2
else:
    smallest = num3

if (num1 <= num2) and (num1 >= num3) or (num1 >= num2) and (num1 <= num3):
    secsmallest = num1
elif (num2 <= num1) and (num2 >= num3) or (num2 >= num1) and (num2 <= num3):
    secsmallest = num2
else:
    secsmallest = num3

#print after collecting input

# 1

# 1 is largest, 3 is smallest
if (num1 == num2) and (num1 == largest) and (num3 == smallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The first number", num1, ', is the same as the second number', num2, ', and the smallest number is',
      smallest,)

# 1 is second smallest, 3 is largest
elif (num1 == num2) and (num1 == secsmallest) and (num3 == largest):
    print(' ')
    print("The first number", num1, ', is the same as the second number', num2, ', and the largest number is',
      largest,)

# 1 is smallest, 3 is second smallest (largest)
elif (num1 == num2) and (num1 == smallest) and (num3 == secsmallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The first number", num1, ', is the same as the second number', num2, ', and the largest number is',
      secsmallest,)

# 2

# 2 is largest, 1 is smallest
elif (num2 == num3) and (num2 == largest) and (num1 == smallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The second number", num2, ', is the same as the third number', num3, ', and the smallest number is',
          smallest,)

# 2 is second smallest, 1 is largest
elif (num2 == num3) and (num2 == secsmallest) and (num1 == largest):
    print(' ')
    print("The second number", num2, ', is the same as the third number', num3, ', and the largest number is',
          largest,)

# 2 is smallest, 1 is second smallest (largest)
elif (num2 == num3) and (num2 == smallest) and (num1 == secsmallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The second number", num2, ', is the same as the third number', num3, ', and the largest number is',
          secsmallest,)

# 3

# 3 is largest, 2 is smallest
elif num3 == num1 and (num3 == largest) and (num2 == smallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The third number", num3, ', is the same as the first number', num1, ', and smallest number is',
          smallest, '')

# 3 is second smallest, 2 is largest
elif num3 == num1 and (num3 == secsmallest) and (num2 == largest):
    print(' ')
    print("The third number", num3, ', is the same as the first number', num1, ', and largest number is',
          largest, '')

# 3 is smallest, 2 is second smallest (largest)
elif num3 == num1 and (num3 == smallest) and (num2 == secsmallest):
    print(' ')
    print("The third number", num3, ', is the same as the first number', num1, ', and largest number is',
          secsmallest,)

# all numbers are the same? do this:
if num1 == num2 and num2 == num3:
    print('All numbers are the same :)')

# no same numbers? do this:
else:
    print(' ')
    print("The largest number is", largest, ', the next smallest number is', secsmallest, ', and smallest number is',
          smallest,)
```

Here is my code, it basically tells you which of 3 inputted numbers is the largest, second smallest and smallest and if any numbers are the same. Everything else is fine, but here is an output when I put 3 numbers in:

```
Input the first number to compare: 10
Input the second number to compare: 10
Input the third number to compare: 10
 
The first number 10 , is the same as the second number 10 , and the smallest number is 10
All numbers are the same :)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there any way that I could get rid of that first line and just keep it to say that all numbers are the same? If so, I would like to know soon, my deadline to coming up :)

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. I think you can make your point with perhaps 5 lines of code. Write some new code which just focuses on the behaviour you're interested in.

Comment: this seems like an incredibly complex way to compare 3 numbers. also im pretty sure there is just something wrong with your comparisons somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy to just use the "all same numbers `if` right after user inputs:

```
# ask for user input
num1 = int(input('Input the first number to compare: '))
num2 = int(input('Input the second number to compare: '))
num3 = int(input('Input the third number to compare: '))

# all numbers are the same? do this:
if num1 == num2 and num2 == num3:
    print('All numbers are the same :)')

else:
    # identify which numbers are largest, second smallest and smallest
    if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
        largest = num1

    #...snipped

    # 3 is smallest, 2 is second smallest (largest)
    elif num3 == num1 and (num3 == smallest) and (num2 == secsmallest):
        print(' ')
        print("The third number", num3, ', is the same as the first number', num1, ', and largest number is', secsmallest,)

    # no same numbers? do this:
    else:
        print(' ')
        print("The largest number is", largest, ', the next smallest number is', secsmallest, ', and smallest number is', smallest,)
```

On another note, why not create a list for these numbers?
That way you can use `min` and `max` for the smallest and largest, and just leaves to somehow get the leftover, the middle one.

Comment: Or use `sort()`

Answer (score 0):

An `elif` (else if) statement will only execute if the if/elif statements before it in the same block evaluate to `False`. By the same block, I mean the run of if-elif....elif. If you then start a new block with another if statement, that will run as normal.

Thus, if you want something to not execute if something else is true, you could put it in an `elif` or `else` block after the initial condition.

If you don't want them located next to each other in code, you could also set a flag and refer back to it later.

See this FizzBuzz Python solution as an example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fizz-buzz-in-python